# How to tokenize words which are not in the dictionary in R?

Tags: r, dictionary

I am working on a set of data which I need to tokenize for training it. Before doing tokenization, I have created a dictionary so that I need to retrieve those words present in the dictionary as such.

My text file is given below:

```
t <- "In order to perform operations inside the abdomen, surgeons must make an incision large enough to offer adequate visibility, provide access to the abdominal organs and allow the use of hand-held surgical instruments.  These incisions may be placed in different parts of the abdominal wall.  Depending on the size of the patient and the type of operation, the incision may be 6 to 12 inches in length.  There is a significant amount of discomfort associated with these incisions that can prolong the time spent in the hospital after surgery and can limit how quickly a patient can resume normal daily activities.  Because traditional techniques have long been used and taught to generations of surgeons, they are widely available and are considered the standard treatment to which newer techniques must be compared."
```

My dictionary includes words:

```
dict <- c("hand-held surgical instruments", "intensive care unit", "traditional techniques")
```

Now I have applied the bigram tokenization for words in the document. For that I have used the following code:

```
#Preprocessing of data
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(t))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,PlainTextDocument)

#Bigram Tokenization
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize=BigramTokenizer, dictionary=dict))
```

But I am getting the output as this:

```
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 3, documents: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1/2
Sparsity           : 67%
Maximal term length: 30
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

                            Docs
Terms                            character(0)
hand-held surgical instruments            0
intensive care unit                       0
traditional techniques                    1
```

But I need to tokenize the words those are not present in the dictionary using bigrams. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check what the dictionary does. It only returns the words in the dictionary.

> dictionary:
>   A character vector to be tabulated against. **No other terms** will be listed in the result. Defaults to NULL which means that all terms in doc are listed.

What you could use is the following code. Beware that removePunctuation also removes the hyphen between "hand-held". There is also no need for it. The tokenizer removes most of the punctiation anyway.

**EDIT:** based on comment

```
#Preprocessing of data
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(t))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus,PlainTextDocument)

#Tokenizers
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
TrigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3))

# dictionary bigrams removed.
tdm_bigram_no_dict <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,control=list(stopwords = BigramTokenizer(dict), tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
# dictionary bigrams from corpus
tdm_bigram_dict <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer, dictionary = dict))
inspect(tdm_bigram_dict)

<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 3, documents: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1/2
Sparsity           : 67%
Maximal term length: 30
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

                                Docs
Terms                            character(0)
  hand-held surgical instruments            0
  intensive care unit                       0
  traditional techniques                    1

# dictionary trigrams from corpus
tdm_trigram_dict <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize = TrigramTokenizer, dictionary = dict))
inspect(tdm_trigram_dict)

<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 3, documents: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1/2
Sparsity           : 67%
Maximal term length: 30
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

                                Docs
Terms                            character(0)
  hand-held surgical instruments            1
  intensive care unit                       0
  traditional techniques                    0

# combine term document matrices into one. you can use rbind since tdm's are sparse matrices. If you want extra speed, look into the slam package.
tdm_total <- rbind(tdm_bigram_no_dict, tdm_bigram_dict, tdm_trigram_dict)
```

Since where are using rowbind there will be double records in there based on the dictionary results. But working further with the data you can transform these into a dataframe like so and use dplyr to group them to a single line:

```
library(dplyr)    
df <- data.frame(terms = rownames(as.matrix(tdm_total)),   freq = rowSums(as.matrix(tdm_total)), row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df %>% group_by(terms) %>% summarise(sum(freq))
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But I need both dictionary words and tokenized words as the output

Comment: This works better!!!! Is there some way that the dictionary words need not to be tokenized. For example I want my output to look like:

Comment: This works better!!!! Is there some way that the dictionary words need not to be tokenized. For example I want my output to look like:                                                                                                                  (abdomen surgeons,
abdominal organs,
access to,
adequate visibility,
allow use,
an incision,
intensive care unit,
hand-held surgical instruments). Here the dictionary words are obtained as such while other words in the document is being tokenized.

Comment: The dictionary is tokenized once, your text is tokenized 3 times and 2 times matched against the dictionary. It is not the most efficient way if you have a huge corpus. Since you want to have the complete strings of the dictionary you run into these kind of problems. At least now you get the match of the dictionary back and the frequency of the term.  As you can see "intensive care unit" does not appear in this text and is not counted or shown in the end result.

Comment: I agree to it. But intensive care unit should also be present for further processing. I am working for a large corpus and I am stuck at extracting complete strings.

Comment: Changed a bit of code so the dictionary results are kept even though they don't appear in the text. Frequency will then be 0.

Comment: I tried it. But I am getting this error: Error: could not find function "%>%"